# For loop in c returning wrong value

Tags: arrays, c

[image of issue with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR3vr.png)

I'm reading a set of numbers from a file (1 2 3 4 5 6 7) and when I print them out in the while loop it returns the correct numbers. In the for loop directly below it, it's returning random numbers (under loop through array). Anyone know what is going on?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if(argc != 2){
      printf("%s\n", "Wrong number of arguments");
  }
  else{
    char* filename = argv[1];
    printf("%s\n", filename);
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int arrSize;
    int array[arrSize];
    int i = 0;

    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &arrSize);

    printf("%d\n", arrSize);

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &array[i]) == 1) {
      printf("%d\n", array[i]);
      i = i+1;
    }

    
    printf("%s\n", "Loop through array");
    for (int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++) {
      printf("%d", array[j]);
      printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  Please do not use images of text — post the code as text in the question.  You'll also need to post more code — it's not possible to guess the problem from what you show.  You need to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: What's in `arrSize`?  How does that compare with what's in `i` after the first loop completes?  What's the size of the array — how many elements are in the array?  It looks like you have some memory overwriting issues, but it is hard to know without sufficient code to be compilable.

Comment: `int arrSize; int array[arrSize];` That's undefined behaviour because `arrSize` is not set when the array is declared. Move `int array[arrSize]` to be after the `fscanf`.

Comment: Kaylum was right, it's fixed now! Thanks so much to you both :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
int arrSize;
int array[arrSize];
int i = 0;

fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &arrSize);
```

When you define `array`, you have no idea what value is in `arrSize`; it is uninitialized.

You need:

```
int arrSize;
int i = 0;

fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &arrSize);

if (arrSize <= 0 || arrSize > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE)
    …deal with error condition…

int array[arrSize];
```

You might want to think about writing the first loop as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize && fscanf(fp, "%d", &array[i]) == 1; i++)
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```

This avoids overflowing the bounds of the array you have allocated.  You then don't need the separate declaration of `i` either.  The braces are optional; I wouldn't use them for a single, simple statement like the `printf()` call, but many people always use them.  The braces become necessary, of course, if the loop is revised to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
{
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &array[i]) != 1)
        break;
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

It's good that you test for `fscanf(…) == 1`; people often mistakenly test against EOF.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this piece of code.

```
int arrSize;
int array[arrSize];
int i = 0;

fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &arrSize);
```

What do you think what will happen?
You are declaring an array without defining its size.

```
int arrSize;
fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &arrSize);
int array[arrSize];
```